# Retrieving data in a list from firebase database table

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Profile table in my firebase database that looks like this
[image]

What I am trying to do is to grab certain values from this table for each instance of profile and list them in the UI. I found another stack overflow post and the solution that worked for them was like this...

here is the home.ts file (this will be where I display up all the users)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ToastController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Profile } from '../../models/profile';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from'@angular/common/http';

import firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  profiles:Observable<any>;
  constructor(public http: HttpClient, private toast: ToastController, public afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    let profiles = this.afDatabase.list('profile').valueChanges();
  }
  }
```

And then in the home.html file, I am trying to display it like this..

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let profile of profiles | async">
        <p>{{profile.bandName}}</p>
        <p>{{profile.bandHandle}}</p>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

I get 0 errors, but absolutely nothing is populating. No values are showing on the UI! Any ideas here as to what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to store the value onto a block scoped variable `profile`. The variable won't be accessible in the html this way.

```
export class HomePage {
  public prolfies: any;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, private toast: ToastController, public afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    afDatabase.list('profile')
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.profile = data;
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work.. get a bunch of syntax errors. valueChanges() does not seem to allow the then()

Comment: Ok yeah, that was my fault, it is an observable. I've updated my answer

Comment: Ah! This did get me further, however I now have an InvalidPipe error.. Looks like the two values I am trying to access from each instance of profiles is coming in as [Object, Object]

Comment: Got it - just needed to remove the async from my ngFor. Thank you!

Comment: Nice, enjoy Angular :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution i wasted lot of time scratching my head :D

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try it, but I think you have to subscribe to your list.

Try:

```
let profiles = this.afDatabase.list('profile').valueChanges()
   .subscribe(value => {
      this.profiles = value;
   })
```

If it didn't work do can you do this in your ngOnInit()

```
ngOnInit(
   console.log(this.profiles)
)
```

And then paste you here your result

Comment: I tried the following, but I dont think this syntax is correct with the Observable. I am not opposed to a different way but I get the following error 'Type {}[] is not assignable to Observables<any>{}[]'. Also, should your example be built off of the constructor as well? If you have this example with a little more code that would help a lot! Also, what I get from the console with the orignial code I had posted is 'undefined'